# Modal dialog doesn't listen to commands when the window is too small

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-2

So I'm helping a friend with her [website](http://www.susanazuniga.com/) to solve a problem that came up with the modal dialog (the website is using the `twitter bootstrap`). The idea is pretty simple, every time you click an image of the carousel a dialog pops up where you can watch a video, and that's that. However, she noticed that when trying to watch a video on the iPad the dialog would close itself when trying to click play, so I checked on Safari and later Firefox (by resizing the window) and the same problem appeared (Chrome seems to be working fine).

At first I thought that, for whatever reason, the browser thought it was clicking outside the dialog so it closed itself (as that is the default behavior), so I added `data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"` to the HTML.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="flex-video widescreen" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;">
                <iframe allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Aq8X4l7aGiU?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
            <p style="text-align:left;"> Colaboración en equipo para el desarrollo del concepto, la historia, aspecto general del corto.<br /> Y desarrollo de tareas personales como, modelación de personajes, personalización de esqueletos automáticos, blend shapes, asistente de texturización, animación 2D, animación de colisiones y compositing.<br /> </p>
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar Video</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And while the dialog is not closing on its own anymore, it won't listen to any commands. The video can't be played (or paused) and the dialog can't be closed until I fullsize the window again. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your modal markup is incorrect; doesn't match the examples in the Bootstrap docs. Try [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint)Ing your webpage, it will point out the errors.

Comment: Ah, you are using Bootstrap 2 instead of Bootstrap 3. Your question is tagged incorrectly.

Comment: @cvrebert Sorry about that, it's fixed now. Should I still try to use Bootlint?

Comment: Bootlint only works for Bootstrap 3.